# WL.SimpleDialog showing full screen in windows 10 mobile and desktop

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MobileFirst `WL.SimpleDialog` appearing fullscreen in windows mobile, windows tab 10. Anybody have faced this issue and have solution please let me know.

[image]

Comment: What is your MobileFirst version and build number?

Comment: Hi idan, MobileFirst version:7.0

Comment: Are you running a Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) or Windows 8 environment on the Windows 10 device ? Also, are you running on a Windows 10 tablet or a phone?

Comment: Hi Vivin, Thanks  for replay. I am using Windows 8 environment for  both Windows Phone and tablet . It appear full screen in all device(Phone and tablet).

Comment: If you're using the WIndows 8 environment on both phone & tablet, is it a unviersal app ? Can you share the project. We did not see similar results.

Comment: Hi Srik, Thanks for replay. There is two environments in IBM MF for generating windows build. One is WindowsPhone8 (Windows8 silver light) .It will gives build for only mobiles. And second one is Windows8(Windows universal) by using this we can generate builds for both phone and tablets.I am using IBM MF simple dialog for display messages and it showing full screen like in the above image. I am using Visual Studio professional 2015 IDE.  I think sharing client project is not ethical. Please share your email id so that we will discuss in offline.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Srik, Thanks for replay. There is two environments in IBM MF for generating windows build. One is WindowsPhone8 (Windows8 silver light) .It will gives build for only mobiles. And second one is Windows8(Windows universal) by using this we can generate builds for both phone and tablets.I am using IBM MF simple dialog for display messages and it showing full screen like in the above image. I am using Visual Studio professional 2015 IDE. I think sharing client project is not ethical. Please share your email id so that we will discuss in offline.

Since you are unwilling to provide your project where this issue is reproducible, either **write a demo app that reproduces it** and provide it, or open an IBM PMR (support ticket) and share it privately with IBM. This is a programming website and you are expected to share code.

If you can't share code, this specific question does not belong here.

Comment: Sharing the peace of code or demo app is not a problem for me.   Please find below code for displaying ibm MF popup  WL.SimpleDialog.show("Alert", "Welcome To IBM MF", [ {
          text : 'OK',
          handler : function() {
          }
         } ]);